# Requisição HTTP usando RAW/JSON Angular 7

Tags: node.js, angular, api, http, angular-6

Boa tarde, já tentei de quase tudo mas não consigo fazer um POST no angular usando uma lista, retorna sempre o erro 500. Essa é a chamada pelo component.

```js
ngOnInit() {
    let CSVProduto: Array<CSVProduto> = [
      {nome: "Lucas", sobrenome: "Rodrigues" , idade: "22" },
      {nome: "Lucas", sobrenome: "Silva" , idade: "25" }
    ];
    this.produtoService.uploadCSV(CSVProduto).subscribe(res => window.alert("Dados inseridos com sucesso")
    )
  }
```

Essa é a chamada pelo serviço.

```js
uploadCSV(CSVProduto: Array<CSVProduto>) {
    console.log(CSVProduto)
    return this.httpClient.post(this.urlUpload, CSVProduto, this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        retry(1),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      )
  }
```

E esse é o código da API

```js
exports.importCSV = (req,res) => {
    try {

        const produto = []
        
        for(var i = 0; i < req.body.CSVProduto.length; i++){

            produto.nome                   = req.body.CSVProduto[i].nome;
            produto.sobrenome              = req.body.CSVProduto[i].sobrenome;
            produto.idade                  = req.body.CSVProduto[i].idade;

            const sqlQry = 'insert into teste (nome,sobrenome,idade) values (?,?,?)'
            
            connection.query(sqlQry,[produto.nome,produto.sobrenome,produto.idade], (err,result)=>{
                
                if(err){
                    try {
                        console.log(err)
                        return res.status(500).json({"message": + err})           
                    } catch (error) {}
                     
                }else{
                    try {
                        return res.status(201).json({"message": result.insertId + " - Dados inseridos com sucesso!"})
                    } catch (error){}
                }
            })
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({"message":"Internal Server Error"})
    }
}
```

Usando o Postman funciona normal, com esse body [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Me desculpem, mas não sei o que estou fazendo de errado, já pesquisei e já testei quase de tudo. Alguém poderia ajudar? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Assim analisando o seu código o objeto que você está construindo é diferente do objeto que você está mandando via post no angular.

Esse é o objeto que você está enviando via postman

```
{
    "CSVProduto": [
        {
            "nome": "AAAA",
            "sobrenome": "teste",
            "idade": "32"
        },
        {
            "nome": "AAAA",
            "sobrenome": "teste",
            "idade": "25"
        }
    ]
}
```

e esse é o código que você está gerando no código do angular

```
[
    {
        "nome": "AAAA",
        "sobrenome": "teste",
        "idade": "32"
    },
    {
        "nome": "AAAA",
        "sobrenome": "teste",
        "idade": "25"
    }
]
```

Existe duas formas do corrigir ou no angular ou no servidor, no servidor é mais "simples" onde o trecho do código que tem

```
...
for(var i = 0; i < req.body.CSVProduto.length; i++){

            produto.nome                   = req.body.CSVProduto[i].nome;
            produto.sobrenome              = req.body.CSVProduto[i].sobrenome;
            produto.idade                  = req.body.CSVProduto[i].idade;
...
```

apenas remova o "CSVProduto"

```
...
for(var i = 0; i < req.body.length; i++){

            produto.nome                   = req.body[i].nome;
            produto.sobrenome              = req.body[i].sobrenome;
            produto.idade                  = req.body[i].idade;
...
```

ou então corrija no código do angular criando o objeto assim:

em vês disso:

```
let CSVProduto: Array<CSVProduto> = [
    { nome: "Lucas", sobrenome: "Rodrigues", idade: "22" },
    { nome: "Lucas", sobrenome: "Silva", idade: "25" }
];
...
uploadCSV(CSVProduto: Array<CSVProduto>)
```

por isso:

```
let CSVProduto: any =
{
    "CSVProduto": [
        { nome: "Lucas", sobrenome: "Rodrigues", idade: "22" },
        { nome: "Lucas", sobrenome: "Silva", idade: "25" }
    ]
}
...
uploadCSV(CSVProduto: any)
```

espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Cara, funcionou. Muito obrigado mesmo, tenha uma ótima semana e muito obrigado mesmoooooo.